# Want an example for using aes encryption method in kernel version above or equal 2.6.38

Tags: linux, encryption, linux-kernel, aes

I know linux kernel has "aes" module internally , so perhaps someone could provide me an example for it , as i'm making a kernel module which utiliser this function.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look at `net/mac80211/aes_ccm.c` for example.  The basic sequence is

- `crypto_alloc_cipher("aes", ...)`
- `crypto_cipher_setkey(...)`
- Do `crypto_cipher_encrypt_one(...)` as much as you need
- `crypto_free_cipher(...)`

Or `net/ceph/crypto.c` gives an example of using AES in CBC mode.

In any case be very careful of how you generate keys and the chaining mode, or else you are likely to make a mistake and do something insecure.